# How to allow any date range with moment.js daterangepicker?

Tags: momentjs

I am using moment.js daterangepicker to accept from and to date from user interface.However,whenever I wish to set the date range more than a month or year the calendar dates auto adjust them to one month  date range.

I have gone through the documentation and tried attribute maxSpan,autoUpdate,etc.
Ranges for Today,last month,etc are working fine.
I need custom range to accept any date range.

```
<script src="resources/js/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
var startDate;
                var endDate;
                var startDateCount = <%= l_startdatecount%>;
                var endDateCount = <%= l_enddatecount%>;
                startDateCount  =   -startDateCount;
                endDateCount    =   -endDateCount;
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#reportrange_right').daterangepicker( {
                        startDate: moment().subtract(startDateCount, 'days'),
                        endDate: moment().subtract(endDateCount, 'days'),
                        minDate: '01/01/2012',
                        maxDate: '01/01/2050',
                        dateLimit: {
                            days: 365
                        },
                        showDropdowns: true,
                        showWeekNumbers: true,
                        timePicker: false,
                        timePickerIncrement: 1,
                        timePicker12Hour: true,
                        ranges: {
                            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment()],
                            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                        },
                        opens: 'right',
                        buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
                        applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
                        cancelClass: 'btn-small',
                        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                        separator: ' to ',
                        locale: {
                            applyLabel: 'Submit',
                            cancelLabel: 'Clear',
                            fromLabel: 'From',
                            toLabel: 'To',
                            customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
                            daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
                            monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
                            firstDay: 1
                        }

                    },
                    function(start, end) {
                        $('#reportrange_right span').html(start.format('D MMMM YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('D MMMM YYYY'));
                        startDate = start.startOf('day');
                        endDate = end.startOf('day');
                    }
                    );
                    $('#reportrange_right span').html(moment().subtract(startDateCount, 'days').format('D MMMM YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().subtract(endDateCount, 'days').format('D MMMM YYYY'));
                    startDate   =   moment().startOf('day').subtract(startDateCount, 'days');
                    endDate     =   moment().startOf('day').subtract(endDateCount, 'days')

                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                 });
</script>
```

Expected output:
Left calendar selects 2018-07-29 then right calendar can select any date from 2018-07-29 to future.

Actual output:
Left calendar selects 2018-07-29,right calendar only allows dates in August 2019 and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution from the forum of moment.js!
I got to add `linkedCalendars:false` and remove

```
dateLimit: {
days: 365
 }
```